# sinatra files in public folder being routed?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have public folder in root of my project. Placed a couple of images, when I try to access them, it says "Sinatra doesn't know this ditty..."

Isn't default public folder supposed to be called "public"? Or do I have to explicitly set that?

Answer (score 1):

Need to not include /public in path.

Answer (score 1):

The folder name should be "public" and then access it with /image.png when your folder structure is public/image.png